# ggplot - change legend labels without scale_fill_discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to change the labels of a legend manually, but it does not seem to work. From other questions, I think it is because i am using group instead of fill, but i don't know what to do about it... here is the graph I am trying to make:

```r
df<-tibble(any=c(1991,1991,1991,1992,1992,1992,1993,1993,1993), per=c(13,25,40,34,5,65,12,56,20), ID=c(1,2,3, 1,2,3,1,2,3))

labels=c("Yellow", "Red", "Green")

ggplot(df, aes(x= any, y= per, group=ID)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=ID)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=ID))+
  labs(title = "ID Colours",
       caption = "Font: Patilla",
       y = "Percentage", x= "Any") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name= "Legend", labels=labels)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please QA the code you give us, your code gives a parsing error (missing `c` before a paren). (I'll fix.)

Comment: It's because the aesthetic you are using is `color`, as in `color = ID`. So you need `scale_color_discrete` not `scale_fill_discrete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is reading your ID as a continuous variable.

You should add `factor()` arround ID and also add `scale_color_discrete` as suggested by Gregor

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= any, y=per, group=factor(ID))) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=factor(ID))) +
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(ID))) +
  labs(title = "ID Colours",
       caption = "Font: Patilla",
       y = "Percentage", x= "Any") +
  scale_color_discrete(name= "Legend", labels=labels)
```

[image]

**Update**

If you also want the colors to match, use `scale_color_manual` instead of `scale_color_discrete`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= any, y=per, group=factor(ID))) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=factor(ID))) +
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(ID))) +
  labs(title = "ID Colours",
       caption = "Font: Patilla",
       y = "Percentage", x= "Any") +
  scale_color_manual(name="Legend", labels=labels, values=labels)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gregor's comment your `ID` variable is a double class.

Try:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x= any, y= per, group=as.factor(ID))) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=as.factor(ID))) +
  geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(ID))) +
  labs(title = "ID Colours",
       caption = "Font: Patilla",
       y = "Percentage", x= "Any") 
p +
  scale_fill_manual(name= "Legend", labels=labels) # incorrect call to scale_fill

p +
  scale_color_manual(name= "Legend", labels=labels,
                       values=labels) # better option
```

[image]

Comment: @Nuria see the update to match colors